# Jquery Ajax find("p") in responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax, responsetext

I would like to isolate a part of my responseText in Jquery and Ajax.

```
$.ajax ({
  url : "/controller/action",
  complete : function (xhr, result)
  {
    if (result != "success") return;
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    var title = $(response).find("p");
    title.appentTo ("#description");   
  }
});
```

I works great for `response` but doesn't when I try to isolate the part between

Can I use : `.find("p")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "_when I try to isolate the part between_"?

Comment: Your code has typos, it should be appendTo with a d, and $("#description") (you are missing the $ operator)

Comment: I correct it but it still doesn't work : I have the same error : 304 Not Modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to correct some typos, but I don't agree entirely with the suggestion.
To me it should be:

```
$(title).appendTo('#description');
```

[note that the tile is inside $()]
cause appendTo can accept selectors too

Comment: `title` is already a jQuery object you don't have to convert it into jQuyer object. `$(response).find("p")` gives you jQuery object so `title.appendTo("#description")` works fine after fixing the typo in `appendTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `success` handler because you are not doing if the response is not `success`?

```
$.ajax ({
  url : "/controller/action",
  success: function (response)
  {
    if (result != "success"){ 
       return;
    }

    var title = $(response).find("p");
    title.appendTo("#description");   
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working. I have an error in the console : 304 Not Modified